Ending a sentence or dialogue with 'would never'?
I was texting some friends when I used the phrase 'would never' at the end of a sentence e.g. 'Imagine being sober on a Friday night - James would never.'
Given modern texting I guess it really doesn't matter, but I am now wondering if ending a sentence or conversation with the words 'would never' is grammatically accurate, as opposed to saying/typing the full sentence e.g. '.... - James would never do something like that.'
I can't seem to find any examples online of sentences ending with 'would never' (and ChatGPT couldn't provide any examples either), but I am pretty sure this is a common expression otherwise I would not have used this particular turn of phrase.

In such contexts, never is just a more emphatic "negator" than not. But precisely because it focuses more attention on the negator makes us less likely to end the utterance at that point. So whereas we're quite comfortable with "You might say that, but I would not", if we switch to never we're much more likely to (re)state the verb being negated: "You might say that, but I would never do so" (or "...I would never say such a thing", or whatever). But syntactically, I don't see any difference between no and never there.

...it may not be all that common, but most of the matches for the 3-word sequence "would never but" in Google Books match the current context. Never ask chatgpt for English usage examples, though. It makes up complete garbage. If you ask it for sentences from Shakespeare ending in "would never" it will probably make some up for you. (It just did for me! :)

The issue is conversation. Coffee? Yes. Not sentences, but clear and common. Yet, no verbs! Hello?

Grammatically speaking, "would never" must refer to "Imagine".
'Imagine being sober on a Friday night - James would never (imagine it).'
That is because the sentence, 'Imagine being sober on a Friday night - James would never being sober', doesn't make sense.
Your original sentence sounds 'off' in my opinion. Of coure it depends what you want it to mean.

But we know that this is not what this means. It means that James would never be sober on a Friday night.
